# How to profile "external" DLL code in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have a DLL that I've built using a separate solution/project that I've embedded into my project.  When profiling CPU speed, I find that the DLL marked as "external code" is a considerable contribution to the overall slowness of my program.  Is there any way I can get the profiling to descend into that external code so I can find out what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Solution was this:

- add the existing vcxproj from the external sln into my project
- profile
- click the filter box and then check "show external code"
- profit

last one is optional

Comment: In my case I was missing the step,  click the filter box and tick "show external code"